# ActiveMQ: how to set DB lock transaction isolation type properly?

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic

In my ActiveMQ configuration I would like to change the default DB lock transaction isolation level to `TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ`.

[API documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/store/jdbc/JDBCPersistenceAdapter.html#setTransactionIsolation%28int%29) writes:

> `public void setTransactionIsolation(int transactionIsolation)`
>
> set the Transaction isolation level to something other that
>   `TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED` This allowable dirty isolation level may
>   not be achievable in clustered DB environments so a more restrictive
>   and expensive option may be needed like `TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ`
>   see isolation level constants in [`Connection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html?is-external=true)

In the XML configuration, the `jdbcPersistenceAdapter`'s `transactionIsolation` attribute accepts only integer-type values, so I cannot use the [`Connection.TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ) constant directly, but only it's [value (4)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/sql/Connection.java#Connection.0TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ) instead:

```
<persistenceAdapter>
    <jdbcPersistenceAdapter dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" dataSource="#mysql-ds" transactionIsolation="4" lockKeepAlivePeriod="5000">
        <locker>
            <lease-database-locker lockAcquireSleepInterval="10000"/>
        </locker>
    </jdbcPersistenceAdapter>
</persistenceAdapter>
```

Is there a way, that I could specify the constant instead of hardcoding number "4"?

As ActiveMQ is Spring-based, I thought I could try to assign it somehow via using [<util:constant>](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-constant), but could not find how to do it...

Answer (score 0):

Try that way:

```
<util:constant id="transactionType" static-field="java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ" />
```

EDIT:

The problem is not in spring but in activemq XML Schema:

```
<xs:attribute name="transactionIsolation" type="xs:integer">
```

So it wont accept any other value than hardcoded int - you can try put property placeholder here:

```
 transactionIsolation="#{myproperty}"
```

but i'm not sure if this will work.

Work around to this problem is to somehow configure activemq by pure spring beans (`bean id=...`) without using dedicated amq tags.
EDIT2: here you have sample config with pure spring tags http://activemq.apache.org/jms-and-jdbc-operations-in-one-transaction.html

Comment: Yes, I was able to read out the constant value, but I cannot pass it to `<jdbcPersistenceAdapter>` as then XML validation fails due non-integer value...

Comment: @Laimoncijus try workaround from EDIT part of my initial answer